# Add Cookie on Javascript Fetch

Tags: javascript, cookies, header, fetch, session-cookies

I need to manually set a cookie session ID to a fetch call.

```
fetch("url", {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "set-cookie": "PHPSESSID=123123; path=/",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
}).then((res2) => { console.log(res2.headers) })
```

When I log the headers that have been sent on 'res2' this is the cookie I see (it's randomly generated for every call)

```
'set-cookie': [ 'PHPSESSID=dj0r4brf9cosngq19bmeuea3hs; path=/' ],
```

1. Is this possible AT ALL? I don't see any clear examples online so that's a warning for me.
2. If it's possible, what am I missing?

Comment: Set-Cookie is a response header, is sent by the server not the client

Comment: The `PHPSESSID` cookie is typically generated by a PHP-powered backend. If you want to send the value back from the client you need the [`Cookie` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie). I've no idea about the *fetch* specific restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm aware of that but the problem is that I'm not able to modify the header whatsoever apparently.

Comment: `console.log(res2.headers)` is logging the **response** headers, not the request headers. As said, the backend will ignore `Set-Cookie` because it isn't expected to handle it. Does it work if you use `Cookie` instead (with the right syntax)?

Comment: Oops! Didn't realize I was logging the response. No it doesn't. I'm going try another approach but I'll leave this open in case anybody went through this already.